# The file "Starting.gif0000.gif" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable

Tags: processing

I am trying to incorporate a .gif document into my Processing code but it appears that something's wrong with the URL. The gif document is in the same folder with my sketch and I don't know what is wrong.

```
Animation animation1;

float xpos;
float ypos;
float drag = 30.0;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  background(255);
  frameRate(24);
  animation1 = new Animation("Starting.gif", 38);
  ypos = height * 0.25;
}

void draw() { 
  background(255);
  float dx = mouseX - xpos;
  xpos = xpos + dx/drag;

  animation1.display(xpos-animation1.getWidth()/2, ypos);
}

// Class for animating a sequence of GIFs

class Animation {
  PImage[] images;
  int imageCount;
  int frame;

  Animation(String imagePrefix, int count) {
    imageCount = count;
    images = new PImage[imageCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
      // Use nf() to number format 'i' into four digits
      String filename = imagePrefix + nf(i, 4) + ".gif";
      images[i] = loadImage(filename);
    }
  }

  void display(float xpos, float ypos) {
    frame = (frame+1) % imageCount;
    image(images[frame], xpos, ypos);
  }

  int getWidth() {
    return images[0].width;
  }
}
```

> Error Message
>
> The file "Starting.gif0000.gif" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
>
> The file "Starting.gif0001.gif" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
>
> The file "Starting.gif0002.gif" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.

Comment: Did you add it to your sketch using the menu in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the class definition. It takes many separate images and makes it a gif as output. What you need to do is to separate the Starting.gif you got into 38 files (if there actually are 38 frames), each named "Starting0000.gif", "Starting0001.gif", "Starting0002.gif" ... "Starting0037.gif".

```
animation1 = new Animation("Starting", 38);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be in a folder called `data`. This folder should be in the same folder of your sketch.

```
SketchFolder

    Sketch.pde

    data

         Image.gif
```

Using the menu to add or dropping the image in the PDE will do this for you. Or you can do it manually.

Comment: Still not working. I have created a data folder under the folder of my sketch.

Comment: see @Vibius Vibidius Zosimus answer. I didn't really read the code so I missed that.